# Why does the TFS forecast tool ignore Active, Resolved items?

Tags: tfs, forecast, backlog

In [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/forecast?view=tfs-2017) article there is a statement:

> The forecast tool ignores Scrum items set to Committed or Done and
> Agile and CMMI items set to Active, Resolved, or Completed.

And so the tool includes in current iteration's forecast such items:

- really moved to the current iteration and really active and resolved;
- and next few iterms really moved to the next iteration;
  WHY they are ignored? They don't complete and the team need time to complete ones!
  I don't understand how to use this tool?
  What kind of process proposed to use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the forecast tool ignores the In Progress Items whether they are shown or hidden. Regarding why they are ignored, I'm afraid it's by design. Once your team has completed a sprint or two, they can use the team velocity to forecast how much of the backlog they can finish within the upcoming sprints. This doesn't include In Process Items, but for Proposed items.

If you have any suggestion for DevOps, feel free to submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Thanks but you mistake.
This option just shows or hide active elements. 
But whatever they won't be counted in forecast whether they are shown or hidden.

By the way I don't understand the value of this option.

Comment: You are correct that the forecast tool ignores the In Progress Items whether they are shown or hidden. Regarding why they are ignored, I'm afraid it's related to the template. Take Scrum as an example, once the state changes to `committed`, there is an obligation to actually deliver all of them at the end of the Sprint.

Comment: ... and so they have to be forecasted at first (current) iteration. But the tool forecast at the current iteration next proposed items. And all backlog is shifted up.

Comment: Once your team has completed a sprint or two, they can use the team velocity to forecast how much of the backlog they can finish within the upcoming sprints. This doesn't include In Process Items, but for Proposed items.

Comment: Why the TFS forecast tool move nearest proposed items to the first (current) iteration?

Comment: Could you give me an example? Please check the forecast result here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/forecast?view=azure-devops#review-the-forecast-results